# Using Elasticsearch Java API to match any of several words, case insensitive

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch for the first time, I'm sure this must be easy but so far a solution has eluded me using the Java API:

I have an array of search terms, and I'd like to return hits matching any of these terms in a case insensitive way.

This code works except it's case sensitive, but I'd like it to be case insensitive:

```
String[] terms = {"orange", "peach"};
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("orders")
    .setTypes("fruit")
    .setQuery(
        QueryBuilders.termsQuery("description", terms).minimumMatch(1)
     )
     .setFrom(0).setSize(10)
     .setExplain(true)
     .execute()
     .actionGet();

for (  SearchHit hit : response.getHits()) {
    String source = hit.sourceAsString();
    //only case sensitive matches found...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using [Terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) query - this doesn't get analysed.

Try replacing it with a [Match](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query or a [Query String](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) query.  These both get analysed and assuming you're using the Standard Analyzer will convert all terms to lowercase.